# New Value EditText not being displayed , no errors whatsoever

Tags: java, android, android-layout

EDIT : By the way , if i hard code edt4.setText("any text")  IN THE SCOPE , it shows the value

EDIT2: tried rebuilding/cleaning project , could this be a bug in settext method, it looks like im doing it right . When i look at other code with settext

EDIT3: startactivityforresult might be my answer ? , i openend another question related to what i wanna try out , i still havent found another solution , stuck with this for a week now : ( 
this is the link to my question                                    [Can i use startActivityForResult , with one activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740939/can-i-use-startactivityforresult-with-one-activity)

EDIT4 : now trying it with making views visible and invisible

I have read every single article about anything related on stackoverflow , dreamincode etc, and i cant find anybody that knows the answer for my problem.

I have a qr scanner and after a successful scan the result needs to be put in a EDIT TEXT field with name editText4 , my code throws no errors but it is NOT displaying any value .

I've posted on different forums but to no avail (https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/412000-settext-is-not-showing-set-value-in-edittext-in-gui/page__st__15__gopid__2372214&#entry2372214) 
, as you can see the commented code . That's pretty much also what I've tried , I think I somehow got to get my handle result method inside of the scope.

NOTE : Log.v outputs the result very well , but when i try anything else with the result it just don't works or being displayed

ps: I m beginner at java

Thanks for your help

here's my mainactivity

```
 ` public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
   ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

 Button sendButton;
 EditText edt4;
 EditText edt2;
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    edt4 = findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    mScannerView = findViewById(xmlScannerView);
    mScannerView.setFormats(ZXingScannerView.ALL_FORMATS);
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();







    EditText delete2;
    Button button3;

    button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    delete2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    final EditText finalEdittext = delete2;
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Clear EditText
            finalEdittext.getText().clear();

        }
    });

    EditText delete4;
    Button button4;

    delete4 = findViewById(editText4);
    button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);

    final EditText finalEdittext1 = delete4;
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Clear EditText
            finalEdittext1.getText().clear();

        }
    });


}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
}


public void onClick(View v){

    RelativeLayout someid = findViewById(R.id.someId);
    mScannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    someid.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}


    // EditText edt4;

    @Override
     public void handleResult(final Result result) {
    //handle result

    Log.v("handleResult", result.getText());


    edt4 = findViewById(editText4);
    edt4.setText(result.getText());
         //edt4.setText(String.valueOf(result.getText()));

       // edt4.setText(new 

   StringBuilder().append("Resultaat:").append(result.getText()).toString());




  }
`
```

this is xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground">


android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

<me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView

    android:id="@+id/xmlScannerView"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
<RelativeLayout

    android:id="@+id/someId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/scan_locatie"
        android:inputType="text"

        android:text=""
        tools:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/scan_qr"
        tools:text="scan qr code" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/scan_order"

        android:inputType=""
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/scan_qr"
        tools:text="scan qr code" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:text="@string/button"
        tools:text="Versturen.." />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:5 also changed XML , and main , still not working :(

Comment: Does `result.getText()` contain a value?

Comment: in log.v it does

Comment: (1) Is there any reason that you declared `EditText edt4;` right before `handleResult()` and not before `onCreate()`? (2) Is there a possibility there exists in your project another view with id `editText4`? (3) Why do you set the text of `edt4` after you show the dialog?

Comment: (1) i was trying some things , (2) i've got a delete button on edittext 4

Comment: dialog isnt neccesary it was just for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `result.getText()` is a `String` anyway, so you could change the following line:

```
edt4.setText(String.valueOf(result.getText()));
```

To:

```
edt4.setText(result.getText());
```

After that you call `updateScannerData`, which is also writing to the `EditText` once again, but from the `UI-Thread`. I would recommend to remove the `UI-Thread` code as well since I assume the code runs on that `Thread` anyway.

Comment: i was just one of the inmiddels millions of things i triedt

Comment: Try to check if only using this line works, try not to call `updateScannerData` to make sure `result.getText()` gets set.

Comment: Try to run it, I can see that your current code will not compile at all.

Comment: it force closes with null pointer  , with the method of the other guy on the other question , ill update my code btw

Comment: its doing something now , but its overlapping the mainactivity and still does not store scanned value in edittext

Comment: What happens if you do the following:  `edt4.setText("Resultaat:" + result.getText());`

Comment: now trying , also , note that i've tried edt.setText("KolereBug") in onCreate , and that worked

Comment: Also clean your project several times, since my experience with Android Studio is that it is quite buggy with deploying.

Comment: does nothing , i think that niza guy has the right method ? because it wont change the view and all , therefore nt losing the value

Comment: edt4.setText("Resultaat:" + result.getText()); throws nullpointer

Comment: could you check my code again , this seemed to work , but still no value is displaying grrrr

Comment: I think it's just getting more messy, no offence. Just figure out why you get the nullpointer. I just guess that `result` is `null`.

Comment: i fixed it already , are u very good in java ? can i add u on whatsapp or something , after a week i finnaly got my scan result in the edittext , but very weird.  I had to put android:text="New Text" in xml (WEIRD) , and the scannerview freezes after a scan (WEIRD), and the weirdest thing is , it can only update edittext if i flip the device , ( it auto-returns from the camera view ) and all of a sudden the scanned result is there (WTF)!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sure, email me. You can find my information on my profile.

Comment: why do you think the value is updating when i tilt the device after the scan , so weird , is there code to return to a updated layout after succesfull scan

Comment: Because it will force the entire view to refresh by default.

Comment: exually tilting does exactly what i want lol , how could i implement the same behaviour , if a succesfull scan takes place

Answer (score 3):

try removing `recreate();`

you are recreating the activity after setting the value, so the previous value is lost

Comment: the recreate is there to resume my activity , because somehow after a scan the scanner view gets frozen and can't return. Its weird but with recreate it's gone and it work good

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
this.finish();     would this be good practice , instead of recreate ? EDIT: it does exactly the same only the transition seems smoother

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
edt4.clear();
```

or

```
edt4.setText("");
```

Comment: see my edit , it works with hardcoded strings IF it's after setcontentview in the scope