# Can i use startActivityForResult , with one activity?

Tags: java, android

EDIT: updated my code , posted more of the code for you to see .
EDIT: why am i being downvoted ? 
EDIT2: broke my code lol , im going to reverse all you're suggestions , and try the xml option provided

i would like to know if i can use `startActivityForResult`  in my main activity.
i'm opening a `scannerview` with the code below , 
what i see as my SECOND `activiy` .

how could i get that result because it's not officially another activity it's only a method.

```
   Button sendButton;
 //EditText edt4;
 EditText edt2;

@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edt4 = findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    ZXingScannerView mScannerView = findViewById(xmlScannerView););
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
    mScannerView.startCamera();          // Start camera on resume
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
}

public void onClick(View v){
    ZXingScannerView mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
   mScannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);       
   mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();


}




//EditText editText4;



EditText edt4;
@Override
public void handleResult(final Result result) {
    //handle result

    Log.v("handleResult", result.getText());
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Ordernummer of Locatie");
    builder.setMessage(result.getText());
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    //edt4.setText(result.getText());
    //edt4 = findViewById(editText4);

    //edt4.setText(String.valueOf(result.getText()));

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          updateScannerData(1,result.getText());
                      }


});
}

private void updateScannerData(int scanType, String scannedCode){

    //startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
    //this.finish();
    edt4.setText(scannedCode);
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
    this.finish();
}
```

XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground">


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/scan_locatie"
        android:inputType="text"

        android:text=""
        tools:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/scan_qr"
        tools:text="scan qr code" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/scan_order"

        android:inputType=""
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/scan_qr"
        tools:text="scan qr code" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:text="@string/button"
        tools:text="Versturen.." />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView

    android:id="@+id/xmlScannerView"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: If `handleResult()` called on non UI thread then you can not show the Dialog directly . And the word `NOT WORKING` does not qualifies the explanation . Check logs for error .

Comment: theyre are no errors , the log.v outputs result correctly but i need to return from the scannerview to the main , thats where the result has to be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, either use multiple `layout groups` in your activity's layout or use multiple fragments.

if you go for the first option, you should add the `ZXingScannerView` in you XML layout and simple tangle it's visibility if you want to use it

```
<me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView
android:width="match_parent"
height="match_parent"
android:id="someId"
android:visibility="gone"
/>
```

And then in your code

```
         private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
                super.onCreate(state);
                setContentView(someLayout);    

                mScannerView = findViewById(SomeId);     
    mScannerView.setFormats(ZXingScannerView.ALL_FORMATS);// dont forget this
mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
            mScannerView.startCamera()
            }
            public void onClick(View v){
              mScannerView.setVisibility(View.Visible);


            }
```

**EDIT**
Call `setFormats` see above and start the camera is the `onCreate()` and change the visibility in the `XML` to `INVISIBLE`

**EDIT 2**

Your `XML` is supposed to be like this

```
     <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground">


        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView

        android:id="@+id/xmlScannerView"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" /> 
    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/someId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/scan_locatie"
            android:inputType="text"

            android:text=""
            tools:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/scan_qr"
            tools:text="scan qr code" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/scan_order"

            android:inputType=""
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/scan_qr"
            tools:text="scan qr code" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="157dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:text="@string/button"
            tools:text="Versturen.." />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And then when calling the `onClick`

```
  public void onClick(View v){

              yourRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.Invisible);
              mScannerView.setVisibility(View.Visible);


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think we need to take a look at your current code and the `ZXingScannerView`. If we take a look at the Github repository of the `ZXingScannerView`, there is an example which differs a bit from your implementation.

First of all, you should call `setContentView(mScannerView);`, only in your `Activity`'s `onCreate()` once. Right now, when you click, the entire view gets redrawn, which is not needed. You also set the `resultHandler` each time when you click on the button, which might cause problems as well.

This code is taken from the Github repo of the element you are using, so please make your `Activity` look like this.

https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

```
public class SimpleScannerActivity extends Activity implements ZBarScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private ZBarScannerView mScannerView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        mScannerView = new ZBarScannerView(this);    // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
        setContentView(mScannerView);                // Set the scanner view as the content view
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
        mScannerView.startCamera();          // Start camera on resume
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        // Do something with the result here
        Log.v(TAG, rawResult.getContents()); // Prints scan results
        Log.v(TAG, rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().getName()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)

        // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
        mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }
}
```

Also note that you will need permissions to access the phone's camera.

Comment: Then move `mScannerView.startCamera();` to the `onClick()` method and initialize your `EditText` first.

Comment: Initalize it in `onCreate()`

Comment: This answer was just a pointing in the right direction. You need to make changes according to your use case. Copy your essential parts to `handleResult()`.

Comment: i did that , but what i had then was everything working , exept the result wouldnt go in edittext , look at this question of mine , if you'd like check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705381/new-value-edittext-not-being-displayed-no-errors-whatsoever

Comment: That's because you call `setContentView(mScannerView);`. `mScannerView` does not contain your `EditText`.

Comment: im not , im sorry that was from previous answer from someone, edited it

Comment: zou je me in de chat willen helpen '?

Comment: Sure, however we need to talk English here.

Comment: do you have enough rep to move to chat  ?

Comment: Well, I don't have any prompt for a chat yet.

Comment: could you view my other question . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705381/new-value-edittext-not-being-displayed-no-errors-whatsoever/51705512#51705512 ,

Comment: what would u say about the method of the other guy reacting ?

Comment: It's a bit of a workaround. This code of me should just work anyway.